# SslSocket в WebView

Tags: java, android

Нужно зайти на сайт с https соединение через свой JCE Provider. Через HttpsURLConnection или OkHttp никаких проблем. Я им устанавливаю свой SslSocketFactory и все хорошо, но ещё необходимо зайти на сайт через WebView. Как это можно сделать?